# How to switch views correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, view

Im trying to use a swipe gesture to switch views. My swipe is working and being handled, but somehow the view switch doesn't function right.

Following code for the swipe handle:

```
-(void)handleSwipeLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{  
    CGPoint location = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:tableView];  
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];  
    if(indexPath){  
        userCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; //userCell inherits from UITableViewCell so why complain?  
        StatisticsViewController *statisticsView = [StatisticsViewController new];  
        [self.view removeFromSuperview];  
        [self.view addSubview:statisticsView.view];  
        //[self.view insertSubview:statisticsView.view atIndex:0];  
    }  
}  `
```

I have previously used the insertSubview: atIndex:0 before, as I have commented out.
My problem is that the new view I'm trying to add is not being added. The removeFromSuperview works in the sense I get a blackscreen (hence removing the view). But I don't understand why I can't add the other view (statisticsView that I create an instance of; I am using storyboard and have a StatisticsViewController with some labels and colors just to test), I just get a blackscreen after removing the view.
Btw, I am working from my rootviewcontroller named FrontPageViewController. **I don't know if it would be more "right" to have a clean view controller (root) that loads in the frontpageviewcontroller and then switch it outs if I need to load another view. (But I don't see why my current approach wouldn't work).**
Thanks in advance

Comment: Im not sure you read my whole post before flaming me. Did you even read what I wrote about my approach; guess not? Bad code or not, your code might just describe what I asked about the approach, not sure.. because your explanation is kind of..bad

Comment: EDIT: guess you removed your next comment after reading further. So will I

Comment: And the only reason I tried to remove my _current_ view from superview was because neither   [self.view addSubview:statisticsView.view]; OR 
        //[self.view insertSubview:statisticsView.view atIndex:0]; is working to show the view I want the user to see. plus I was first trying [super.view addSubview...........] then trying self.view in frustration I guess^^

Comment: use this at will be called once if([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)

Comment: zaheer, I don't understand that. Your words are a little twisted too. Could you elaborate? But I don't have problems with the gesture (I am just using a gesture to do the switch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You main problem is because you are adding your new view to the same view you just removed. You should add it to its parent view.

About your aproach sadly I can't use comments to clarify some points but you shouldn't be doing the view switching like that.

You shouldn't be replacing the view from the controller, you should be switching between controllers.

You could do that by creating a segue with an identifier in the storyboard and adding the following to you gesture handler method:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"MySegue" sender: self];
```

If your only intention is to replace a view in the same controller you should be creating it (just the view and not the controller) programatically and not by adding a view from one controller to another.

If you need any help with the segues I recommend you start by reading the "Add a Segue to Navigate Forward" from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/SecondTutorial.html

To manually perform a segue you will need to choose an identifier to the segue you created.

Comment: I am intending to switch between view controllers, hence presenting to the user the different views that the various view controllers hold(how to do this by code?); maybe my explanation was a little bad, sry about that:) The reason for my approach about a view controller that handles the switching between other view controller is that the book I've been reading did that at some point. Any points you could clarify will be greatly appreciated, as I feel this is pretty basic to how to structure an app.

Comment: If you intend to switch between controllers you should be using segues. You could take a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/SecondTutorial.html

Comment: I will be looking into that right now, ty. I was looking at this function call [self presentViewController:statisticsView animated:YES completion:nil]; (but it results in a blackscreen; though without removing view). Am I right in structuring my app with different view controllers that I switch between to presents the user with my different "screens/pages"

Comment: Wouldn't my parent view be my rootviewcontroller/initial controller? Thanks for your help and reference though, helped me